# Strange size of picture taken with Android Camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm developing an Android application, using Android Camera API in order to open a preview, and take photo from it. The application must work in portrait mode only, and it must be possible to use both the front and the back camera of the device (if the device has both the cameras).

I have open the preview in my app, I have set properly the display orientation (rotating it of 90 degrees with the method: [mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int))) to make possible to see the application-preview in portrait mode, and I have added a button that enables the switch between front and back camera. All these things work properly in the application.

The problem is when I take a photo: in order to rotate the taken photo in the correct way (in portrait), I get dinamically the orientation of device and rotate the picture as the gotten orientation. But, when the photo is saved into Gallery, the photo size is strange: it's full screen if it has been taken using front camera, and not if it has been taken with back camera. My goal is to take photo always in full screen.

These two screenshots show the problem:

---BACK-CAMERA PHOTO:

[image: BACK-CAMERA PHOTO]

---FRONT-CAMERA PHOTO:

[image: FRONT-CAMERA PHOTO]

Here, there is my code of the CameraPreview:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        return;
    }

    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
    }

    try {
        // Start preview in portrait mode
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        // Set the list of supported preview size in the related variable
        if(mCamera != null){
            if(mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes() != null){
                mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            }
        }

        // Get the parameters of camera
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        // Set output format to NV21 (which is guranteed to be supported on all devices)
        parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

        // Set the correct preview size (after applying the getOptimalPreviewSize)
        if(mPreviewSize != null) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            Log.d(TAG,"Preview size is ("+mPreviewSize.width+";"+mPreviewSize.height+")");
            // initializing bitmap and pixels
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            pixels = new int[mPreviewSize.width * mPreviewSize.height];
        }

        // Correct the size - orientation of picture taken
        if(isTablet(getContext()) == Boolean.FALSE){
            onOrientationChanged(getScreenRotationOnPhone(),parameters);
        }else{
            onOrientationChanged(getScreenRotationOnTablet(),parameters);
        }

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        // Set to turn the Flash ON
        // parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

        // Call the setPreviewCallback and onPreviewFrame to get the incoming frame
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame ( byte[] data, Camera camera){
                Log.i(TAG, "Ma entro nella onPreviewFrame?");
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
                Log.i(TAG, "Il formato del frame e': " + format);
                //YUV formats require more conversion
                if (format == ImageFormat.NV21 || format == ImageFormat.YUY2 || format == ImageFormat.NV16) {
                    int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
                    int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;                        
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private int getScreenRotationOnPhone() {
    final Display display = ((WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0){
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
        return Surface.ROTATION_0;
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90){
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
        return Surface.ROTATION_90;
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180){
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT");
        return Surface.ROTATION_180;
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270){
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE");
        return Surface.ROTATION_270;
    }else{
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOT_ADMISSIBLE");
        return -1;
    }
}

private int getScreenRotationOnTablet() {
    final Display display = ((WindowManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0){
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
        return Surface.ROTATION_0;
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90){
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT");
        return Surface.ROTATION_90;
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180){
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE");
        return Surface.ROTATION_180;
    }else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270){
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT");
        return Surface.ROTATION_270;
    }else{
        System.out.println("SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOT_ADMISSIBLE");
        return -1;
    }
}

public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
    boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
    return (xlarge || large);
}

public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation, Camera.Parameters mParameters) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(CameraActivity.getOpenedCamera(), info);
    Log.i(TAG, "onOrientationChanged -> Camera opened actually is: "+CameraActivity.getOpenedCamera());
    orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
    int rotation = 0;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
    } else {  // back-facing camera
        rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "onOrientationChanged -> Orientation of pictures setted to: "+rotation);
    mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
}
```

Here, there is the onPictureTaken code of CameraActivity, and the method for switching camera:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File pictureFile = Utility.getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't create file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG,"Couldn't create file");
        return;//?
    }else{
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "File not found exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"File not found: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "IO Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        //Per farle comparire subito nella cartella le foto:
        this.mPictureFile = pictureFile;
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                new String[]{this.mPictureFile.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "ExternalStorage Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i(TAG, "ExternalStorage -> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });
        camera.startPreview();
        imageSaved.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

public void switchCam(){
    if (hasFrontCam == Boolean.TRUE && hasBackCam == Boolean.TRUE) {
        // The phone has front camera and back camera
        if(openedCam==Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
            //Chiudi la preview
            if (mCamera!=null){
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
            //Apri la nuova camera
            mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            init();
            openedCam=Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
        }else{
            //openedCam==Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
            //Chiudi la preview
            if (mCamera!=null){
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
            //Apri la nuova camera
            mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            //riprendi la preview
            init();
            openedCam=Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        }
    }
}
```

using this method of utility:

```
/** Create a File for saving an image */
public static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d(TAG,"Failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        return mediaFile;
    }else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        Log.d(TAG,"External storage not writable but only readable");
        return null;
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG,"External storage not writable");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Someone could help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I notice that the picture flipped. is that right?

Comment: Where is the code that switch between the front and back cam.

Comment: Yes, the picture is flipped to correct the orientation with which it is saved into Gallery. The change works, in fact the orientation of the photo is correct. I have also added the method for switching camera.

Comment: did surfaceChanged get called after cam switch?

Comment: I've just verified with the logcat that if I press the switchCam button, it's called before switchCam() and then surfaceChanged()..

Comment: sentence not clear, switchCam then surfaceChanged. right?

Comment: Sorry if I was not very clear with my answer. It is as you say: switchCam and then surfaceChanged. This order can affect the size with which photos are saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

I've found the solution in the list of supported picture sizes for the back and the front camera.

In my case, I am using a Samsung S4 for the development, and the list of supported picture sizes, for back-camera, is:

```
0) (4128*3096) aspect_ratio=1.333 ---> Choosen automatically
1) (4128*2322) aspect_ratio=1.777
2) (3264*2448) aspect_ratio=1.333
3) (3264*1836) aspect_ratio=1.777
4) (2048*1536) aspect_ratio=1.333
5) (2048*1152) aspect_ratio=1.777
6) (1280*720) aspect_ratio=1.777
7) (640*480) aspect_ratio=1.777
```

For front-camera:

```
0) (1920*1080) aspect_ratio=1.777 ---> Choosen automatically
1) (1440*1080) aspect_ratio=1.333
2) (1280*720) aspect_ratio=1.777
3) (960*720) aspect_ratio=1.333
4) (720*480) aspect_ratio=1.5
5) (640*480) aspect_ratio=1.333
6) (320*240) aspect_ratio=1.333
```

Assuming that the size is (width;height) and the aspect ratio is calculated as: width/height.

Android chooses automatically the best picture size both for front and back camera; it doesn't check if the sizes choosen for front and back camera have the same aspect ratio. But the aspect ratio must be the same, to have in the Gallery photo of the same size.